# Why php exec, system and passthrough functions stopped working if FPM is enabled

Tags: php, server, exec, fpm, pass-through

Hello Guys I am average in server configuration.I am using php exec function to run some commands in my website.But it stopped working if i enable PHP-FPM.
Anybody knows why it cause this issue ?
Below is php function to run the command

```
$cmd="pdftk " . $pdf_to_fill . " fill_form " . $fdf_file . " output $outputfile 2>&1";
exec($cmd, $output, $return_var);
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score -1):

This can be a few things, first, try to confirm if exec is enabled, if safe mode is enabled, and if we're in a jailed shell.

The first two can be done with this script, just see what it outputs when you access it:

```
if(function_exists('exec')) {
    echo '<h1>exec is available.</h1>';
}
if( ini_get('safe_mode') ){
    echo '<h1>Safe mode is on.</h1>';
}
```

The jailed shell is a little harder to detect, but running `var_dump(scandir('/bin/'))` will give an indication, if it has a lot less files in it than if your run `ls -ltr /bin` from the command line, then you're in a jailed shell.

Also, it may be worth using the full path of the pdftk binary, and if it still doesn't work, try running `is_executable` on the path for pdftk.